# How to combine 4 arrays into one

Tags: php, arrays, json, combinations

```
// get date this week

$W = date('W',strtotime(date('Y-m-d'))); 
$sunday = date(datetime::ISO8601, strtotime(date('Y') . "W" . $W . "0")); 
$this_week = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($sunday));
echo $this_week;

//looping for get all date this week

for ($i=1; $i <= 6; $i++) { 
    $date=date_create("$this_week");
    date_add($date,date_interval_create_from_date_string("$i days"));

    $date_week[] = date_format($date,"Y-m-d"); //value array
    $event[] = "dinner"; // value array
    $start[] = "start"; // key array
    $title[] = "title"; // key array

}
```

I want to change it into a json like this

```
        {
            title: 'dinner',
            start: '2015-08-24'
        },
        {
            title: 'dinner',
            start: '2015-08-25'
        },
        {
            title: 'dinner',
            start: '2015-08-26'
        },
        {
            title: 'dinner',
            start: '2015-08-27'
        },
        {
            title: 'dinner',
            start: '2015-08-28'
        },
        {
            title: 'dinner',
            start: '2015-08-29'
        }
```

Comment: Use `array_combine()`

Answer (score 0):

i think this better good... = 
This is still in the looping.

```
$output[] = [
    'tile' => 'Dinner',
    'start' => $date_week
];
```

This is still in the looping.
then in json_encode.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to combine all those arrays. You can build the data structure you want all in one simple loop

```
$W = date('W',strtotime(date('Y-m-d'))); 
$sunday = date(datetime::ISO8601, strtotime(date('Y') . "W" . $W . "0")); 
$this_week = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($sunday));


$result = array();

for ($i=1; $i <= 6; $i++) { 
    $date=date_create($this_week);
    date_add($date,date_interval_create_from_date_string("$i days"));

    $result[] = array('title' => 'dinner', 'start' => date_format($date,"Y-m-d"));
}

echo json_encode($result);
```

The result is

```
[
    {"title":"dinner","start":"2016-11-21"},
    {"title":"dinner","start":"2016-11-22"},
    {"title":"dinner","start":"2016-11-23"},
    {"title":"dinner","start":"2016-11-24"},
    {"title":"dinner","start":"2016-12-25"},
    {"title":"dinner","start":"2016-12-26"}
]
```